# Running a function blocks the bot - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I was trying to search data from four files (they're 4GB large) using a command typed on discord.
The execution time of the search function takes about ten minutes to iterate through the 4 files; when I tried to type the command twice in a row, the second command get executed after the first command get executed (about 10 minutes later).

```
def main(self):
    @self.client.command()
    async def fsearch(ctx, *args):
        self.client.loop.create_task(self.searchTask(ctx, *args))
```

`self.searchTask` is the searching function.

Is there any idea to let the function execute without blocking the bot? (after a while the bot goes offline during the execution.)

### Update:

This is a code snippet from the `self.searchTask` function:

```
async def searchTask(self, ctx, *args):
    found = False
    name = args[0].lower().
    surname = args[1].lower()
    await ctx.send("Searching data...")
    with open(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/out.txt", "w") as fwrite:
        flist = os.listdir(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/datab")
        for x in flist:
            with open(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/datab/{x}", "rb") as f:
                for line in f:
            ...


   fwrite.close()
   if found:
       await ctx.send("Done! Here's the result:")
       await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/out.txt"))
   else:
       await ctx.send("Can't find data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have blocking functions in asynchronous code. It seems `searchTask` is blocking and so your event loop is grinding to a halt. Asyncio event loops provide a simple [API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) for running blocking functions in a threadpool or processpool to keep them from blocking your event loop.

EDIT: Example: Run file operations in thread

```
def search_files():
    found = False
    flist = os.listdir(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/datab")
    for x in flist:
        with open(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/datab/{x}", "rb") as f:
            for line in f:
                found = found or is_found(line) # check your condition in is_found
    return found

async def searchTask(self, ctx, *args):
    name = args[0].lower()
    surname = args[1].lower()
    await ctx.send("Searching data...")
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with open(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/out.txt", "w") as fwrite:
        found = await loop.run_in_executor(None, search_files)
        # write something to fwrite
        # also do this in executor if it's a lot

   fwrite.close() # this is unnecessary if you as using 'with'
   if found:
       await ctx.send("Done! Here's the result:")
       await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/out.txt"))
   else:
       await ctx.send("Can't find data")
```

Comment: `self.searchTask` is not a sync function, is an async one.

Comment: Can you post the code for it?

Comment: Done, code updated.

Comment: @ClownDown Well, the code is still incomplete, so this makes it hard to tell for certain, but I‘m still convinced that `searchTask` is blocking. Your code does not automatically work asynchronously because you declared it with `async def`. The event loop can only step out of your code when your code yields the control back to the loop with `await` for example. If there is a lot of computation between two `await`s then your event loop is blocked for that time.

Comment: The missing code is just iterating over the files and check if the name and surname is in a line.

Comment: ...which can take quite some time when your files are 4G big :-)

Comment: I know, so I can't execute blocking asynchronous functions without blocking the bot, can I?

Comment: You can, if you refactor out the blocking bits. I'll try to update my answer with an example based on your code.